# Three20 comunication between datasource items and TTTableViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, three20

I'm developing an application, and I decided to use three20 + TTTableViewControllers for settings-like page.

So I have my ViewController:

```
@interface MyViewController : TTTableViewController
```

That initalizes my datasource:

```
-(void) createModel {
    self.dataSource = [[[MyDataSource alloc] init] autorelease];
}
```

My datasource then initalizes different kind of controls (some three20 standard, some custom classes), for example

```
UISwitch* switchy = [[[UISwitch alloc] init] autorelease];
TTTableControlItem* switchItem = [TTTableControlItem itemWithCaption:@"UISwitch" control:switchy];
self.dataSource = [TTListDataSource dataSourceWithObjects:switchItem,...,...,nil]
```

Now there are a few things that are not clear to me..

1- How can I access data from the viewcontroller? (ie: Read the value of the switch).. Right now i use something like

```
bool ron = ((SwitchTableItemCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0]]).switchField.isOn;
```

that onestly looks terrible.

2- How can I set the viewcontroller as a delegate for the items (ie: I want have MyViewController as a delegate for all the text fields)

3- What's the best way to add/remove a field. Right now I just reassign the datasource from scratch but again, looks a bit ugly

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1- How can I access data from the viewcontroller? (ie: Read the value of the switch).. Right now i use something like

You should access the data source directly:

```
self.dataSource.items
```

this is an `NSMutableArray`.

> 2- How can I set the viewcontroller as a delegate for the items (ie: I want have MyViewController as a delegate for all the text fields)

It depends on what you want to do. The only item I see in your code is a `UISwitch`, which has no `delegate`; but if the item had one, I would do:

```
 MYItem* switchy = [[[UISwitch alloc] init] autorelease];
 switchy.delegate = self;
```

> 3- What's the best way to add/remove a field. Right now I just reassign the datasource from scratch but again, looks a bit ugly

Since `self.dataSource.items` is an NSMutableArray, you can remove items from it thorugh [`removeObjectAtIndex:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/removeObjectAtIndex%3a) and add through [addObject:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/addObject%3a).

Comment: Thanks, I was not sure about when to use items. Just a question about the delegate, you're setting the datasource as a delegate.. Is that a good practice? What if want MyViewController as a delegate and not the datasource? Thanks again

Comment: In: `switchy.delegate = self;`, I don't know what `self` is (it's your code!), but I assume it is a controller; if you have a controller that is both datasource *and* delegate, no problem; if controller is not datasource, than I would set `delegate` to the controller and `datasource` to the data source...

Comment: sorry, just read the original question again and was not clear. self is referred to a controller that implements a TTListDataSource. So yes, I think the best bet is to use that as a delegate. To me the obvious delegate would be the viewcontroller for a delegate, but maybe I'm overthinking it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For basic setup of TTableviewcontroller of three 20,

use this link http://www.raywenderlich.com/656/introduction-to-three20

Comment: That tutorial is one of the first I read, but doesn't explain any of my questions really..

Comment: Try this http://cybersam.com/programming/tttableviewcontroller-showmenuforcell-example